How to enable Strong Skipping mode in Jetpack Compose? Using Groovy
I'm trying to optimize the performance of my Jetpack Compose UI by enabling Strong Skipping mode. I've read about the benefits of this mode, but I'm unsure how to actually enable it in my project. my gradle files are in Groovy Not in kts
I added this to my app/build.gradle file
android { ... }

composeCompiler {
   enableStrongSkippingMode = true
}

when i sync the project i'm getting the following gradle error
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method composeCompiler() for arguments [build_duzdc886dgg5uy4aejl1ily6m$_run_closure6@4fe2ec36] on project 


-----------------------
root/build.gradle

buildscript {
   kotlinVersion = "1.9.24"
   composeBOMVersion = "2024.06.00"
   composeCompilerVersion = "1.5.14"


   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.2")
    }
 }

subprojects {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {

            freeCompilerArgs += [
                    "-P",
                    "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:stabilityConfigurationPath=" +
                            project.absolutePath + "/compose_compiler_config.conf"
            ]


            if (project.findProperty("composeCompilerReports") == "true") {
                freeCompilerArgs += [
                        "-P",
                        "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination=" +
                                project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_compiler"
                ]
            }
            if (project.findProperty("composeCompilerMetrics") == "true") {
                freeCompilerArgs += [
                        "-P",
                        "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:metricsDestination=" +
                                project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_compiler"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}


-----------------------
 app/build.gradle

    android {
        ...
        compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    
        buildFeatures {
            compose true
        }
    
       composeOptions {
            kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "${composeCompilerVersion}"
        }
       ...
    }
    
    composeCompiler {
        enableStrongSkippingMode = true
    }


Have you tried upgrading to Kotlin 2.0.0?

Nope, it's a big migration for my current project. It's in the pipeline.

Put in in the bottom of the root build.gradle file, I'm using groovy script
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile) {
    compilerOptions.freeCompilerArgs.addAll(
            "-P",
            "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:experimentalStrongSkipping=true",
    )
}

